# TestFlight audio stream not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio-streaming, testflight

I built an app that streams a music library song from one iOS device to another. The app works great on any device when I run it through Xcode. However, when I run the the app through TestFlight, less that a second of audio plays, then it goes silent. I was wondering what could be causing this problem.

I tested unaltered code on the same devices. It worked through Xcode, and it didn't through TestFlight.

More detail about how my code works:

I use an AVAssetExportSession to export the song to a local URL, which I use to initialize an NSData object. I send the data object over bluetooth in packets using the GameKit framework.

I receive the data, again using GameKit, and parse it using Audio Stream Services. I then buffer and play it using Audio Queue Services. These are both under the Audio Toolbox framework.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

So I tried the "old fashioned way" of opening the IPA file in iTunes and syncing it to the device. This works fine. So distribution through an iTunes sync works, while distribution through TestFlight doesn't.

Comment: Yet distributing through TestFlight yields a different functionality than distributing directly through an iTunes sync (also a direct Xcode run). I'm posting this in the off chance that someone else has encountered this problem before (as I do understand it is quite a specific problem). Thanks for the input, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you do a direct xcode run on your iDevice does it work? Are you doing a release build for Testflight and a debug build for direct xcode run? If so do you have code in your application that modifies things based on a release or debug build?

Comment: One more thing... Are you using TestFlight SDK? If so try disabling it and. I have had issues with Testflight sdk tying up my network connect when running in my app sometimes. This is a known issue. Sometimes it affects the network sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, this is something I would really like to look into for a personal project. Could you advise me on where best to learn how to do this?

Comment: i how you do it? i need similiar work to be done any help would be great! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the following steps:

1. Settings -> Safari -> Delete cookies and data
2. Settings -> General -> Profiles -> delete them all
3. Delete your old app
4. Create a new build in test flight
5. install from testflight
6. run app, see what happens, and look in the device console and logs
7. If that won't help try a different stream URL and see if it happens there too

p.s. I encountered some problems with testflight where an old NSUserDefaults data was redownloaded to a device. Wierd but happened.